# Ubuntu 12.10 and Android bluetooth pairing problem

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, android

I'm trying to pair my Android device (Galaxy Wonder Android version 2.3.6) to my Acer Aspire 4741G running Ubuntu 12.10 via bluetooth. Both my phone and the laptop discover one another, but when I start pairing with my phone it generates a pairing request with a passkey but no dialog that asks me to enter the pass key appears on the laptop so pairing fails, when I start pairing via the laptop by adding a new device, it discovers my phone but no pairing request appears on my phone so pairing fails too.
Any help?

Comment: no one knows ?!

Answer (score 1):

If it sees the device, select the device.
Pin Options, choose  custom, type in whatever number you want, then Ok.
It will ignore your custom passkey but send a pin to the device, accept on the device and tell Ubuntu it matches.  The device should pair.  I've tried this with Nokia and Samsung devices and successfully paired them.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to type in a 5-digit custom pin to get it to send the pin to the device. A 4-digit pin didn't work but a 5-digit custom pin did get it to send a different pin and display it on the pc as well.
VeryNewbie